# Add property to JQueryStatic interface

Tags: jquery, typescript, tsd, typescript-typings

I want to add a property `someString` to the `JQueryStatic` interface so I can access it with `$.someString`.

In `index.ts`, I have this code:

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    someString: string;
}

$.someString = "string";
```

`$` is of type `JQueryStatic`, however I get the following error:

> Property 'someString' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of an ambient type declaration that extends the jQuery type declarations like this:

```
declare interface JQueryStatic {
     someString: string;
}
```

put it in a `.d.ts` file somewhere in your code and make sure it's included (or not excluded) in your `tsconfig.json`.

**Why does this work?**

The `declare` bit is what makes this "ambient" - as in "there exists somewhere a `JQueryStatic` which has a `someString` member". TypeScript is smart and picks up that there is also another `JQueryStatic` ambient declaration elsewhere (in your case the jQuery typings and "merges" them together in a single `JQueryStatic` interface declaration.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The existing type information for `$` is in a declaration file (which you probably downloaded). If you'd like to merge your new interface declaration into the existing interface, put your declaration into a `jquery-extensions.d.ts` file:

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    someString: string;
}
```

If necessary, add a reference path to this new file at the top of your code:

```
/// <reference path="../path/to/jquery-extensions.d.ts" />
```